# Creating a simple drop-down menu in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

This really seems simple enough yet for some reason I'm missing something critical.

I have a view:

```
<% form_for :foo, @foo, :url => {:action => 'bar'} do |f|%> 
  <%= f.collection_select :range, FooModel::MONTHS%>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit", :disable_with => "Submitting..." %>
<% end %>
```

I have a model:

```
class FooModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  MONTHS = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep']
end
```

And I have a controller:

```
def new
  @foo = FooModel.new
end

def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
  end
end

def bar
  if params[:foo]
    @foos = params[:foo].inspect
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
  end
end
```

My question is, how do I get at the information as to which combo box element had been selected when the Submit button was clicked? It doesn't seem to be params[:foo], @foo, or anything else I can think of.

**Update**
Looking at it it seems like I should maybe be calling params[:range]? That, however, is nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code can be simplified to work this way:

```
<% form_for @foo, :url => {:action => 'bar'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :range, FooModel::MONTHS %>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit", :disable_with => "Submitting..." %>
<% end %>
```

Using collection_select for simple cases such as this one is probably overkill.  f.select should be sufficient.

Comment: Changed it to that, now I'm getting: undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class on the first line.

Comment: Is this code in your new action? If not, you might want to try replacing @foo with FooModel.new.

Comment: Ah ha, right you are I needed to move that into the right place. Now it's telling me I have a undefined method `select_tag' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x4dce8f0> on the f.select_tag line

Comment: Updated my post. I was using select_tag instead of select. My bad.

Comment: Changed it back and updated it to look like your solution. Getting this on that line undefined method `range' for #<PlayerEventTracking:0x4bb6340>

Comment: @hector use `f.select` instead of `select_tag` . that's what associates the data with the object the form is for (using `form_for`)

Comment: @hector, my guess is that you don't have an attribute named range on FooModel.  That's why you're getting the undefined_method error.

Comment: I updated my view code in my question. That is rendering to the page, the list is being populated, and I can click submit. I would have guessed the selected item's data would have been stuck into :range but it seems like, while not nil, it is empty.

Comment: @hector, it's best to not update your question with a working example as that defeats the purpose of having a Q&A forum where something is not working as expected in the question and the answer clarifies or fixes the problem.

Comment: True enough, sorry about that. Reverted.