# Getting user input from a Rails select form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

This is related to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856201/creating-a-simple-drop-down-menu-in-rails) but I thought it would be best to split it up for searchability later.

I have a Model:

```
class FooModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  MONTHS = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep']
end
```

I have a View:

```
<% form_for @foo, :url => {:action => 'bar'} do |f|%>
  <%= select :range, :thing, FooModel::MONTHS%>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

And I have a Controller:

```
def index
  @foo = FooModel.new
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
   end
end

def bar
    @events = params.inspect

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
  end
end
```

I've tried to access the value that should be getting passed via the drop-down menu a number of different ways but it doesn't seem to be getting passed. Even calling params.inspect only sets @events equal to an empty hash. I suspect something is off with my flow or being called the wrong way or that I'm calling the wrong thing period.

Currently index is where the view up there ^^ lives and when you click on submit it calls bar. Do I need to be passing a variable in a different way? Thanks.

**Update**
Perhaps this is a lead. I believe I have an understanding of what's going on in the model and the control but something still bugs me about the view. In <%= select :range, :thing, FooModel::MONTHS%> what do range and thing actually refer to? When I read tutorials and such online as best as I could tell these fill out the html id and name tags with values but I don't know much else. Do I need to be initializing them anywhere? Do they refer to anything in particular?

Answer (score 2):

I tried this out.  I was also attempting to do the constants approach.  Which worked only after I changed `:month` to the name of the column in the DB that was setup in my `FooModel`

After i got this working I wanted to move it out of `constants.rb` file and put it in the model. Doug was correct and saying that we could access it via `FooModel::Months`

So my final code looks like this in this experiment;

Model:

```
class FooModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  MONTHS = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep']
end
```

View:

```
<% form_for @foo, :url => {:action => 'bar'} do |f|%>
  <%= f.select :month, options_for_select(FooModel::MONTHS)  %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit", :disable_with => "Submitting..." %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def index
  @foo = FooModel.new
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
   end
end

def bar
    @events = params.inspect

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
  end
end
```

At some point i could see using the `constant.rb` for common things like Months, Countries etc. but for this limited experiment I wanted to test it both ways.  If i use the `constants.rb` them my View would look like below.

View if using constants.rb;

```
<% form_for @foo, :url => {:action => 'bar'} do |f|%>
  <%= f.select :month, options_for_select(MONTHS)  %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit", :disable_with => "Submitting..." %>
<% end %>
```

@hector: hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use a constant for this.

1. in `lib/initializers` create a file called `constants.rb` or whatever you want
2. Then add you constant, in your case `MONTHS` *see code below
3. Then you can access that constant in the form

In `config/initializers/constants.rb`:

```
MONTHS = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep']
```

In your view:

```
<% form_for @foo, :url => {:action => 'bar'} do |f|%>
  <%= f.select :month, options_for_select(MONTHS)  %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit", :disable_with => "Submitting..." %>
<% end %>
```

`options_for_select` just formats it for the select input.

Comment: Make sure you restart your server. `constans.rb` is loaded when the server starts.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue.  I used the exact same code as the OP and my bar action populated the @events variable.

Comment: I put it in there as you suggested and it came back with undefined method `month' for #<FooModel:0x4cf13b8>

Comment: You need to declare months as a constant in an initializer like I pointed out :)

Comment: @Sam - MONTHS is fine being defined in the model. It can be accessed as FooModel::MONTHS.  Putting it in a separate constants file may be overkill.

Comment: Yeah, but why would you have a model with nothing in it beside declaring a constant.

Comment: Might as well create a constant.rb file for all constants. but you are right it has nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately while I liked Sam's answer and it does make some improvement to my code it ultimately wasn't the answer to my question. Frustratingly enough the answer was that in my view I had a debug line that I was using to see what output I was getting after the control would run and I was printing from the wrong variable. A simple copy/paste oversight.